# Displaying .png image as if it was a .gif image

Tags: html, image

I have a .png image. But in the  tag i say it's a .gif image. The image is displayed correctly. This is not an elegant way to go but I have hundred of images of them.

I'm asking, what are the consequences of this?

Comment: The tag? you mean like this: `<img src="myimage.gif" />`?
As long as the server sends it with the appropriate HTTP headers, most browsers will have no problems displaying it.

Comment: Yes. But myimage is actually a PNG

Comment: The last letters of the filename mean nothing to the browser -- the browser sends a MIME-Type along with it, as long as that says "image/png", you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No consequences. The filename does not matter to the browser. Only the MIME type does.